# Convert Multipolygon to use it to filter species occurence with spocc::occ

Tags: r, shapes

Hi all I have a shapefile which I want to use to filter species occurences. But the funtion of spocc::occ cant use multipolygons. How can change the format to use it for this function.

```
#area of interest
shape <- st_read("...BaW.shp")
shape

Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 6 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 7.511393 ymin: 47.5338 xmax: 10.49182 ymax: 49.79137
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  USE RS       RS_ALT               GEN SHAPE_LENG  SHAPE_AREA                       geometry
1   2 08 080000000000 Baden-Württemberg    1298892 35801397076 MULTIPOLYGON (((9.646341 49...

#download occ points for one species
df <- spocc::occ(query = 'Gentiana lutea', from = 'gbif', has_coords = T, geometry = shape_bw[1], date = c('1970-01-01', '2022-12-31'))
```